# Solana SOL transfers with variable amount

Tags: python, solana

I am writing a python script using string commands from the solana CLI set. Particularly, 'solana transfer -- ...' In the command string is the specific amount to be transferred. If I specify the amount in the CLI, it is successful.

However, I want to allow user input such as:
amount = float(input(" How much??  ")).
If I use 'amount' in the string, instead of an actual integer or float, I get an error.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: You are missing a opening quote on the `input` function argument.

Comment: That was a typo when writing it here. The python code actually reads:  amount = float(input ("How much??"))